# ubuntuを起動するたびにキーボードレイアウトの設定がリセットされる

Tags: linux, ubuntu

VirtualBox上でUbuntu 17.10を使っているのですが、起動するたびにキーボードレイアウトがリセットされてしまいUSのキーボードとして認識されます。

そのため、毎回起動後に`dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`を実行して設定しなおすということをしています。

これを毎回設定せずにJISキーボードとして認識させるにはどうすればいいのでしょうか?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

設定ファイルを直接変更してみてください。

```
/usr/share/ibus/component/mozc.xml
<layout>○○<layout>を<layout>jp</layout>

/etc/default/keyboard
XKBMODEL=◯◯をXKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT=◯◯をXKBLAYOUT="jp,jp"
```

参考：
[Ubuntu日本語フォーラム / キーボードレイアウトを設定してもすぐに戻ってしまう](https://forums.ubuntulinux.jp/viewtopic.php?pid=112097)